# Inserted value is not visible to the second query

Tags: c#, mysql

There are two tables **customer_invoice** and **sold_item_details**

- in customer_invoice table there is column, **cus_inv_id** (PK)
- This **cus_inv_id** is a foreign key to the sold_item_details

Here is my abstract view of the code,

```
public void txtRent_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){

    /* This method will Insert values to the customer_invoice table */
    CreateOrder();

   /* This method will Insert values to the sold_item_details table*/
   InsertOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem);
}
```

Here is my question when insertion query is executed the second query raise a MysqlException of **Cannot add or update a child row.** I checked in between **CreateOrder() and InserOrderItem()** whether the insertion process has completed surprisingly it turns out it has succeeded.

for example if i insert value set with **cus_inv_id = 1** it will be inserted to the table **customer_invoice** but when inserting to the **sold_item_details** table with **cus_inv_id (FK) = 1** it raise that exception.

These are the two codes related to those two methods. (I have removed some columns for the ease of the problem)

---

```
public void CreateOrder()
    {
       _connection.open();
        var mysqlTrans = _connection.BeginTransaction();
        var orderId = -1;
        MySqlDataReader sqlDataReader;

        try
        {
            const string query =
                "SELECT cus_inv_id FROM customer_invoice " +
                "WHERE customer_id = @cusId";

            var mysqlCommand1 = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection, mysqlTrans);
            mysqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusId", customerId);
            sqlDataReader = mysqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                sqlDataReader.Read();
                orderId = (int) sqlDataReader["cus_inv_id"];
            }
            sqlDataReader.Close();

            if (orderId == -1)
            {
                var mysqlCommand2 = _connection.CreateCommand();
                mysqlCommand2.Connection = _connection;
                mysqlCommand2.Transaction = mysqlTrans;

                mysqlCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(cus_inv_id) FROM customer_invoice " +
                                            "HAVING MAX(cus_inv_id) IS NOT NULL";

                sqlDataReader = mysqlCommand2.ExecuteReader();
                if (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    orderId = (int) sqlDataReader["MAX(cus_inv_id)"] + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    orderId += 2; 
                }

                sqlDataReader.Close();

                mysqlCommand2.CommandText =
                    "INSERT INTO customer_invoice(cus_inv_id)" +
                    " VALUES(@cusInvId)";

                mysqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusInvId", orderId);
                mysqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            mysqlTrans.Commit();
            _connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex);
            mysqlTrans.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

---

```
 public void InsertOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        _connection.open();
        var mysqlCommand = _connection.CreateCommand();
        var mysqlTrans = _connection.BeginTransaction();
        mysqlCommand.Connection = _connection;
        mysqlCommand.Transaction = mysqlTrans;
        try
        {
            mysqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(sold_item_id) FROM sold_item_details " +
                                       "HAVING MAX(sold_item_id) IS NOT NULL";

            var sqlDataReader = mysqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            var lastSoldItemId = 1;
            if (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                lastSoldItemId = (int) sqlDataReader["MAX(sold_item_id)"] +1;
            }

            sqlDataReader.Close();

            mysqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sold_item_details(sold_item_id,cus_inv_id) VALUES(@soldItemId, @cusInvId)";

            mysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldItemId", lastSoldItemId);

            mysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusInvId", orderItem.OrderId);

            mysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mysqlTrans.Commit();
            _connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            mysqlTrans.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In createorder you prepare a query to add to the invoice and never run it. So, it wont be there

Comment: @BugFinder sorry for my mistake I have missed to include that code in the question. That code perfectly running if I check middle of CreateOrder() and InsertOrderItem whether the value has sent to the database or not it would result positive answer.

Comment: @LahiruJ Please provide the full exception message, with all the information available from the exception, any more detail than "Cannot add or update a child row".

Comment: @LahiruJ Also, please add the missing code which loads/creates the `OrderItem` object. Also other variables are missing like `customerId`. Please provide the full source code you have.